# converting Apache.dsw to Apache.sln using vs2013

Tags: apache

I am converting Apache.dsw to Apache.sln using vs2013 but some of dependency are getting broken. Can you please anyone assist me to convert it.

Currently I am converting using vs2008 and then the Apache.sln of vs2008 to Apache.sln vs2013 . so I want to skip the conversion through vs2008.

Comment: I think you need to refine your question and provide exact details on the errors that you receive. Otherwise this seems to be a help for process and too broad.

Comment: to build Apache , I have to convert Apache.dsw to Apache.sln if I take vs2013 but it's not getting converted correctly. One option I have to covert it using vs2008 and then vs2013 but I dont want to use vs2008.

Comment: Error: support\htdbm.dsp: Unable to convert project.Please make sure this is a valid Visual C++ 6.0 project.